# get html code from a div

Tags: html, file, jsp

Im getting the html code from div with html() like this :

```
var s = $("#content").html();
```

and sending them to create a new page with this content with ajax :

```
 $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "create.jsp",
                data: {PageContent: s,
                      AppName: name,
                      header : temp
                        },
                dataType: "html"
           });
```

and this is how I create it with java :

```
 File strFile = new File(strPath);

Writer objWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(strFile));
objWriter.write(header);
objWriter.write(content);
objWriter.write(" </div>");
objWriter.write(" </body>");
objWriter.write("</html>");
objWriter.flush();
objWriter.close();
```

Everything is good except when I open the new file I found all the html code in one line ! anyone knows a solution?

> Update

it seems that the `html()` method is extracting the code in one line as i tested ! so is there any solution?

Comment: is everything in one line in the `content`?

Comment: @lucumt of course no !

Comment: you can test write `content` line by line,each time when finished reading a line,call the `newLline` method

Comment: @lucumt how is that exactly ?

Comment: @lucumt PS: the `header` content is written in the new file line by line!